# Error with CMV Print tool when operational layers are turned on

Tags: configurable-map-viewer

I am new to JavaScript and have used the CMV to jump start my first application. I am getting an error on the print tool when I have any of my operational layers turned on; print works find with Esri basemap data only.  I am sure that I am just missing something in my configuration.

Answer (score 2):

This will depend on the version of CMV you are using.

The print tool was updated in the most recent version to be asynchronous. Also, have a look at the log files in the ArcGIS Manager to see why the print tool is failing.

Comment: Thank. It is the most recent version.  I looked at my logs in manager and there is nothing regarding the print error.

Comment: OK, getting logs on manager now that I made a change in the VIEWER file to send request to my ArcGIS Server print utility.  The logs seem to indicate that the request was sent/received successfully, but still getting an error in the app: REST request successfully processed. Response size is 49330 characters.

Comment: Not sure why you would need to make a change in `viewer.config` to get errors logged in ArcGIS. Is this a secure print service (via a proxy)? If ArcGIS is happy then it has to be something to do with the actual request, like a timeout as @tmcgee suggests. Do the browser developer tools give you any indication of why it is failing?

Comment: I originally had the print task using arcgisonline printing service instead of my arcgis server printing service, which was the change that I made in the viewer.js file.  The error that I am getting in Chrome development console is Controller.js:545 error, which is pointing to console.log(option, options[option]).  Not sure if that is at all helpful.  Thank you, everyone, for your help.

Comment: What is the actual console message written in the console?

Comment: The error in the console just reads: "source Print
Controller.js:545 error Error, try again".  It does not appear to be a time-out, because the error is immediate.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps your Print Task is taking a long time. In this case, the Print widget would show an error because the timeout (default of 30 seconds) was reached before the task had actually completed. Despite this "error", the request would eventually complete and show as successful in the server logs.